# VUE CLI 3 - Testing Single-File Components with Mocha + webpack

Tags: testing, vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, vue-cli-3

I am trying to follow the documentation mentioned here [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-single-file-components-with-mocha-webpack).

Below is what I currently have set up.

**Project setup:** Vue CLI 3.2.1 with Node v8.11.2

**devDependencies**:

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
"@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.28",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.1.0",
"cross-env": "^5.2.0",
"eslint": "^5.8.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
"expect": "^24.0.0",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
"jsdom": "^13.2.0",
"jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"mocha-webpack": "^1.1.0",
"node-sass": "^4.10.0",
"nyc": "^13.1.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
"webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
```

And `nyc` config inside `package.json` also:

```
"nyc": {
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.(js|vue)"
    ],
    "instrument": false,
    "sourceMap": false
  },
```

**vue.config.js**:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const path = require('path')
let isCoverage = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'coverage';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
        // use absolute paths in sourcemaps (important for debugging via IDE)
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]',
        devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]?[hash]'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ].concat(
            isCoverage ? {
                test: /\.(js|ts)/,
                include: path.resolve('src'),
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
                options: { esModules: true }
            }: [],
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        )
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: "inline-cheap-module-source-map"
}
```

My test folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My test code looks like this:

[image]

So far I tried running these commands:

```
"test-ci": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config vue.config.js --require test/setup.js test/**/*.js"
"cover": "cross-env NODE_ENV=coverage nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text npm run test-ci"
```

If I run **test-ci** it will output this:  `WEBPACK  Compiled successfully in 631ms`
But it is just a blank page after if I ran **cover**, then the output comes out as nothing being log by `nyc`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and including vue and js files separately fixed it for me.

```
"nyc": {
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "src/**/*.vue"
    ],
    "instrument": false,
    "sourceMap": false
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite using node v10.16.0 and vue-cli 3.11.0, I faced the same problem here. Mohit's answer didn't worked, but the following syntax did:

```
// package.json
  "nyc": {
        "extension": [
            ".js",
            ".vue"
        ]
  },
```